# Как найти среднее арифметическое всех элементов одной колонки sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite3

[image: П]

Вот база данных. Как мне найти среднее арифметическое чисел находящихся в колонке bellang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT AVG(bellang) AS bellang_avarage FROM table;
```

Comment: как именно записать данное значение в переменную.Вы написали sql запрос

Comment: Так вы задавайте вопрос правильно. Вы спрашиваете как найти, а не как записать в переменную. result = cursor.execute(SQL).fetchone()[0]

Comment: Прошу прощения,моя ошибка.Благодарю